# Unable to see folder directory in localhost

Tags: apache, mamp

I am trying to get a website to run locally on my Mac.

I have installed MAMP and both Apache and MySQL Servers are running.
I have tested MAMP and got the initial "Welcome" message where they tell you all is fine and to delete the default index.php file from MAMAP/htdocs.

I delete this file and in MAMP/htdocs I create a test folder called Hello and the folder for the website called Want.

The website I am trying to run locally is an existing website and I have FTP access to the code. I have downloaded all the files and folders for Want to my desktop. I now put all Wants content in MAMP/htdocs/Want.

In the browser I go to localhost and I can see my 2 folders I created in there: Want and Hello see screen grab.

[image]

If I click on the Want folder, the browser just times out. I don't see a sub directory with all of Want's files and folders in it.

To test its working I create a hello.php file and place it in Hello folder. In localhost I select Hello and can see my hello.php file in there and clicking on it just echoes back hello - as was intended.
[image]

I then remove all content from Want folder and copy hello.php into the Want folder. This works perfectly and I can see the hello.php and clicking on it echoes Hello back.

But when I copy back the content of Want back into the Want folder, the browser just times out again when I click on the Want folder to view the sub directories.

I have also tried just copying index.php from the original Want folder into my Want folder but still the browser just times out.

Does anyone have any idea what can be causing this?

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem with index.php. What goes on there?

Comment: You mentioned that you downloaded a full existing website onto the want directory, check to see if there's a .htaccess in there that's causing some kind of trouble

Comment: Its just a standard landing page for the website. I have also tried copying other .php folders from the original Want folder to see if its the index.php that is the problem, but no files or folders show up. The browser just times out. Can it be because a Framework is used? Do some frameworks require additional setup perhaps?

Comment: No there is no .htaccess that I can see

Comment: Does the access / error log show anything? If you remove just the `index.php` file from the `Want` folder, do you see everything else fine? Try to rename `echo.php` to `index.php` and put that in the `Want` or `Hello` folder, does it work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. What I managed to do was to delete `.htaccess` and to write it once again. The problem was that I had a SPACE between one of the ">".